# Update Account object Custom field from Case object trigger

Tags: apex

I am trying to update Account custom field Account_Case_Email__c from Case object Trigger whenever a new Case is being created , I want to concatenate Case custom field value to the account custom field.

```
trigger CaseEmailTrigger on Case (after insert,  after delete) {

    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert){
        CaseHandler.handleAfterInsert(Trigger.New, Trigger.newMap);
    }

    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isDelete){
        
    }

}
```

Handler:

```
public with sharing class CaseHandler {

    public static void handleAfterInsert(List<Case> newCase, Map<Id, Case> caseMap) {

        Set<Id> caseId = Trigger.newMap.keySet();
        List<Case> allCase = new List<Case>();
        
        for (Case eachCase:[Select AccountId,Account.Account_Case_Email__c, Case_Email_Custom__c FROM Case Where Id IN : caseId]){
            eachCase.Account.Account_Case_Email__c = eachCase.Account.Account_Case_Email__c+', '+eachCase.Case_Email_Custom__c;
            System.debug(eachCase.Account.Account_Case_Email__c);
            allCase.add(eachCase);
        }
        update allCase;
    }
```

Comment: Is there any error you are facing? and If there is multiple cases on a given Account... every time you create a Case that field on Account will be overriden by this trigger. And if its one Case per Account, you can also create a Formula field instead of a trigger or you can update using a workflow/flow/process builder

Comment: NO I am not facing any error. In Log I am getting value from Account Email and Case Email both, but its not getting concat and not updating over Account record. I am considering a situation for multiple cases on account updating and all value from cases shoould be concatenated and updated to Account custom field Account_Case_Email__c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the issue of continually appending to a string aside...

When you insert/update an object, it is only the data *on that object* that is inserted or updated. Any data on related objects is ignored.

So when you `update allCases;`, the update is only being applied to the data on the `Case` records themselves. The change you're making to the related accounts are discarded.

The quick fix for this one is to change `List<Case> allCase = new List<Case>();` to instead be `List<Account> relatedAccounts = new List<Account>();`. In your loop, you would then need to add items to this list (similar to how you're adding cases now). `relatedAccounts.add(eachCase.Account);`

`eachCase.Account` is a fully-fledged instance of the `Account` SObject (and custom relationships like `My_Custom_Lookup__r` are also fully-fledged instances of their respective SObjects).

#### That said

There are other improvements you could make to this trigger handler (you could get rid of the query entirely if you were to add a formula field to pull in that data from the related Account, as you only need a record Id to update a record).

But really, the use case I'm imagining for what you're trying to accomplish is probably better served by simply including this `Case_Email_Custom__c` field in the "Case" related list (which you can alter by editing the Account page layout(s)).

Comment: Thanks @Derek for clarification. :-)